# IntelliJ - Use JDK 11 and Eclipse Compiler

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, javac

I use IntelliJ 2018.3 and I need to use JDK 11.

The project compile on Eclipse `(the Eclipse compiler)` but not on IDEA `(the Javac compiler)`

[image]

So I decide to use Eclipse compiler on IDEA (Eclipse compiler 4.7.2) but I have always this error :
[image]

Is there any solution to compile my programm on IntelliJ with the Eclipse compiler and if yes, How can I do that ?

Comment: Did you choose project bytecode version as 11?

Comment: @VineethChitteti yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use JDK 9 or lower, it's not supported for Java 10 and 11 yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-190791 (Eclipse compiler specific limitation).

You can increase the heap size of the JVM running the build process and switch back to javac compiler instead of using Eclipse compiler:

[image: build process heap size]

This should fix the first error.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki yes, but not when using Eclipse compiler. So the answer is correct.

Comment: I can't use lower than JDK 11 so I tried to increase the size and it work. tnx.

Comment: It is maybe a stupid question but eclipse use the eclipse compiler and I tried to run the project on eclipse (with JDK 11) and it works. is that because the Eclipse compiler on IDEA is obsolete or it is more complex ? :/

Comment: @charlesLgn IntelliJ IDEA bundles an older version of Eclipse compiler.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve `OutOfMemoryError` during `javac` compilation you can pass the command line flags `-J-Xms256m -J-Xmx256m` to increase the memory.

This can be done in `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler` menu under `Additional Command Line Parameters` field.

Comment: @charlesLgn do note that CrazyCoder's answer points to `Build process heap size` option which is the right place to manage this setting.